# Nokogiri Builder: Replace RegEx match with XML

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, nokogiri

While using Nokogiri::XML::Builder I need to be able to generate a node that also replaces a regex match on the text with some other XML.

Currently I'm able to add additional XML inside the node. Here's an example;

```
def xml
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.chapter {
      xml.para {
        xml.parent.add_child("Testing[1] footnote paragraph.")
        add_footnotes(xml, 'An Entry')
      }
    }
  end.to_xml
end

# further child nodes WILL be added to footnote
def add_footnotes(xml, text)
  xml.footnote text
end
```

which produces;

```
<chapter>
  <para>Testing[1] footnote paragraph.<footnote>An Entry</footnote></para>
</chapter>
```

But I need to be able to run a regex replace on the reference `[1]`, replacing it with the `<footnote>` XML, producing output like the following;

```
<chapter>
  <para>Testing<footnote>An Entry</footnote> footnote paragraph.</para>
</chapter>
```

I'm making the assumption here that the `add_footnotes` method would receive the reference match (e.g. as `$1`), which would be used to pull the appropriate footnote from a collection.

That method would also be adding additional child nodes, such as the following;

```
<footnote>
  <para>Words.</para>
  <para>More words.</para>
</footnote>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a spin on your code that shows how to generate the output. You'll need to refit it to your own code....

```
require 'nokogiri'

FOOTNOTES = {
  '1' => 'An Entry'
}
child_text = "Testing[1] footnote paragraph."

pre_footnote, footnote_id, post_footnote = /^(.+)\[(\d+)\](.+)/.match(child_text).captures

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.chapter {
    xml.para {
      xml.text(pre_footnote)
      xml.footnote FOOTNOTES[footnote_id]
      xml.text(post_footnote)
    }
  }
end
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter>
  <para>Testing<footnote>An Entry</footnote> footnote paragraph.</para>
</chapter>
```

The trick is you have to grab the text preceding and following your target so you can insert those as text nodes. Then you can figure out what needs to be added. For clarity in your code you should preprocess all the text, get your variables figured out, then fall into the XML generator. Don't try to do any calculations inside the Builder block, instead just reference variables. Think of Builder like a view in an MVC-type application if that helps.

`FOOTNOTES` could actually be a database lookup, a hash or some other data container.

---

You should also look at the [`<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-3C-3C) method, which lets you inject XML source, so you could pre-build the footnote XML, then loop over an array containing the various footnotes and inject them. Often it's easier to pre-process, then use `gsub` to treat things like `[1]` as placeholders. See ["gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) in the documentation, along with this example:

```
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = 'this is[1] text and[2] text'
footnotes = {
  '[1]' => 'some',
  '[2]' => 'more'
}

footnotes.keys.each do |k|
  v = footnotes[k]
  footnotes[k] = "<footnote>#{ v }</footnote>"
end
replacement_xml = text.gsub(/\[\d+\]/, footnotes) # => "this is<footnote>some</footnote> text and<footnote>more</footnote> text"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.chapter {
    xml.para { xml.<<(replacement_xml) }
  }
end
puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <chapter>
# >>   <para>this is<footnote>some</footnote> text and<footnote>more</footnote> text</para>
# >> </chapter>
```

Comment: I did consider the splitting option, but figured it could end up quite messy once there we're several footnote references. I suppose there's unlikey to be more than a few in any one paragraph but still, I'll wait in case someone has a better solution before accepting. Thanks Tin man.

Comment: See the added example.

Comment: There's a bit to chew on here. It's getting late here so I'll go through this in the morning.

Comment: Can you give me the link of `xml.text` ? I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Thanks I [over looked](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-text) it.. :-)

Comment: This looks to do the trick. The only thing I'll need to do is assign the footnotes pre-process an XML fragment (as the contents will need additional children). Ex. `footnotes[k] = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml| xml.root { xml.footnote { xml.para v } } }.doc.root.child` (`para` is just one possible child node) Would that be about right?

Comment: I've always found the easiest thing is to do it using string processing, then inject the final result. Trying to do it using Builder methods needlessly complicates it. Nokogiri supports injecting XML/HTML content strings for a reason, so take advantage of it.

Comment: After implementing this into my program I decided to keep the Builder approach; there's many different node types within (DocBook) `<footnote>` and as I already have methods for generating the various nodes, I can just utilise them and actually save myself a lot of work. Thanks for the help Tin Man, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can try as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

def xml
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.chapter {
      xml.para {
        xml.parent.add_child("Testing[1] footnote paragraph.")
        add_footnotes(xml, 'add text',"[1]")
      }
    }
  end.to_xml
end

def add_footnotes(xml, text,ref)
  string = xml.parent.child.content
  xml.parent.child.content = ""
  string.partition(ref).each do |txt|
    next xml.text(txt) if txt != ref
    xml.footnote text
  end
end

puts xml
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <chapter>
# >>   <para>Testing<footnote>add text</footnote> footnote paragraph.</para>
# >> </chapter>
```

Comment: When I tried this with multiple footnote references (using .scan to collect them) the output became jumbled (not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong).It's getting late here so I'll try again in the morning.

Comment: @MichaelCook I will also edit the answer, that I missed. Please have a look at it later. Suggest me if any change is needed. I will update it. Although your post is very nice. Some confusions I have. But let me complete it, then do check and comment for further changes.

Comment: Okay, I am scanning the text to collect up all the references and then iterating over these; `references_found_by_scan.each { |ref| ... }`  inside which the `string.partition(ref).each` code is run. This though is duplicating parts of the text and I don't know how to prevent that. I hope that is clear.